# How to write an XPATH expression having ::Before ::After CSS tags

Tags: xpath

```
<span id="fdf84803-be9a-43c5-8dd2-1d53b888be3b" unselectable="on" class="k-input-inner">
<span class="k-input-value-text">Select a Gender</span></span>
<span class="k-input-value-text">Select a Gender</span>
::Before
'Select a Gender '
</span>
```

I want to write an XPath with contains text "Select a Gender". I tried this as below but its not working.

```
 //span[contains(text(),'Select a Gender')]
```

Comment: <span id="fdf84803-be9a-43c5-8dd2-1d53b888be3b" unselectable="on" class="k-input-inner"><span class="k-input-value-text">Select a Gender</span></span>
<span class="k-input-value-text">Select a Gender</span>
::Before
'Select a Gender'
<span class="k-input-value-text">Select a Gender</span> This is the CSS code

Comment: Please update HTML since you have 3 opening tags and 4 closing. Also clarify which `span` node exactly you want to select

Comment: I don't think the tree XPath operates on contains any pseudo element contents you inject with CSS `::before` or `::after` so I think using XPath you simply can select those pseudo elements or select nodes based on pseudo element contents, it is not part of the DOM tree XPath operates on.